# Post images are not displayed on the front page

Tags: php, bug

I don't get any errors, but the post images are not displayed on the front page, all other pages displays the images correctly. How can I fix this? Here is the site

The front page is set to display the recent posts.

This is the index.php file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    // get options
    $pinthis_infinite_scroll = get_option('pbpanel_infinite_scroll');
?>

<section id="content">
    <div class="container fluid">
        <?php if (is_category()) { ?>
            <div class="category-title">
                <div class="container">
                    <h3 class="title-3"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php if (category_description()) { ?><div class="description"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div><?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>
        <div class="boxcontainer">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('pinbox', get_post_format()); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
            <?php
                ob_start();
                posts_nav_link(' ', __('Previous Page', 'pinthis'), __('Next Page', 'pinthis'));
                $pinthis_posts_nav_link = ob_get_clean();
            ?>
            <?php if(strlen($pinthis_posts_nav_link) > 0) { ?>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="posts-navigation clearfix <?php if ($pinthis_infinite_scroll == 1) { ?>hide<?php } ?>"><?php echo $pinthis_posts_nav_link;  ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="notification-body">
            <p class="notification tcenter"><?php echo __('No posts found.', 'pinthis'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Could you show your code? Because you're getting an undefined `src` in your images.

Comment: I don't know which one is, it seems to be the same function as for the rest of the pages which displays the images correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Something that generates the image links is broken. You are not getting a valid `src` attribute in the `title` tag. The result is:

```
<p class="thumb">
    <a href="http://paper-backgrounds.com/red-grunge-concrete-texture-3/" title="Red Grunge Concrete Texture">
    <img src="undefined" alt="Red Grunge Concrete Texture" height="132" width="236">
    </a>
</p>
```

Without that `src` attribute the image can't load.

As you don't post the code that generated that HTML I can't say exactly how to fix it, but should you post that code (as an edit to the question) I am pretty sure it is an easy fix.

Comment: I don't know which file have the code for front page display

Comment: Nor do I. You will have to  dig through your theme.

Comment: It is the same function as for the rest of the pages which works, very strange.

Comment: @MarioM, then something is wrong with the way that function is written, though (as before) I can't guess at what without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code.

```
if (wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID))) {
    $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
    $data .= '<img alt="blog-img" title="blog-img" class="img-responsive" src="' . $thumbnail_url . '"/>';
}
```

Comment: In which php file? My front page is set to display the recent posts.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code